# Could not find implicit [...] parameter F: scalaz.Functor[Iterable] with Scalaz OptionT

Tags: scala, functor, scalaz

I have the following code:

```
OptionT(currentFactors.values).map(_.priceHistory.toList)
```

- `currentFactors.values // Iterable[Option[A]]`
- `priceHistory // Vector[Double]`

However I get this error: `could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.Functor[Iterable]`.

I had the same kind of problem when using `scala.Future` with `OptionT` but solved it by mixing-in `scalaz.std.FutureInstances`.

However, I can't manage to solve this problem. What do I need to do? At the same time, what is a `Functor` of `Iterable` (or `Future`)?

Comment: I don't believe scalaz provides instances for Iterable. You can likely do `OptionT(currentFactors.values.toList)`

Comment: That solves the problem! You can add it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalaz does not provide a `Functor` instance for `Iterable`. A simple solution is to change to a `List`:

```
OptionT(currentFactors.values.toList).map(_.priceHistory.toList)
```

Answer (score 2):

ScalaZ does provide functor for future:

```
import scalaz.syntax.functor._
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture.futureInstance

val future: Future[Int] = ???
future ∘ {_ + 1}
```

For `Iterable` it does provide certain typeclasses (like `Foldable` and `Equal`), but not `Functor` because it will not satisfy functor laws (`Set` is an `Iterable`)
So just do `toVector` or `toList` to use collection ScalaZ does have functor for.

Comment: Thanks. the `futureInstance` is helpful.